# h:commandButton not calling action

Tags: jsf

```
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Home" action="/index?faces-redirect=true"/>
        <p:dataTable var="people" value="#{tableBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" 
            rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink}  {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            lazy="true">  
            <p:column>
                <h:commandButton value="Call Action" action="#{bean.call(object)}/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Using request scoped for call(Object object). However, this method is not called when I click the button.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any sense. Are you sure this is your real code?

Comment: So you don't include nor `<h:head>` nor `<h:body>` in your code? Anyway, mark your bean at least as `@ViewScoped` and will work.

Comment: I am using Spring's `@Controller` with the `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)`. Spring does not provide `@ViewScoped`. Am I able to do it using request scoped?

Comment: No, you're not. Try using `@SessionScoped`. You can also emulate `@ViewScoped` in Spring, just seek for it on the net. I remember that a popular one is from [Cagatay's](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/), but you can use another implementation out there.

Comment: It works using `@ViewScoped' and `@SessionScoped`. But I need it to work using `@RequestScoped` as I require the updated data to be shown upon refresh of the browser.

Comment: You can achieve that using `@ViewScoped` as well. It would be better if you post your real problem instead of the *desired* solution you're working in.